# How can I get the seletced filename from file button?

Tags: jquery, html, css, file-upload

I wanted to try using a link to trigger a hidden input file button, but after I click the link I want to get the selected file.

**css**

```
{#upload {display:none;}}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".file-image").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#upload:hidden").trigger('click');
   console.log($("#upload"));             
});
```

**html:**

```
<a href="#" class="file-image">Add image</a>';
<input id="upload" type="file"/>';
```

How can I get the value of the selected filename of the the upload-button?

In the console I see that object is like

```
[input#fileupload, context:document, selector: "#upload"]
[0]: input#upload
...
...

value: c:\temp\file.jpg //and this value seems to be correct
...
```

I tried with `$("#upload")[0]['value']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$("#upload")[0].files;
```

Comment: Oh thank you! You answered what I was looking for, but is there a way to retrieve the path as well?

Comment: No. Where the user decides to store a file on their own file system is not something that any *web* app needs to know.

Comment: I need the full path for previewing the selected pic.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld — No, you don't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded (see also http://xyproblem.info/ )

Comment: Ok I understand by @Mohd Abdul Mujib answer that I could use readURL() but I didn't manage the code to work as I expected. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `readAsDataURL` method of the [FileReader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) Object.

This is the function that I had used, you can draw the refrences...

```
        function readURL(input) {

            num = jQuery(input).attr("data-opti");
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {

                    jQuery('#preview' + num).attr('src', e.target.result);
                    var logoHeight = jQuery('#preview' + num).height();
                    if (logoHeight < 104) {
                        var margintop = (104 - logoHeight) / 2;
                        jQuery('#preview' + num).css('margin-top', margintop);
                    }
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            } else {
              // no files selected it seems
            }
        }
        jQuery(".imageinput").change(function () {
            readURL(this);
        });
```

This can be used to show a preview of the image even before the file has been uploaded, so it is a pretty nifty feature to enhance the UX.